# How can I use Voila Jones algorithm in MATLAB 64 bit?

Tags: matlab

How can I use Voila Jones algorithm in MATLAB 64 bit?

```
close all
clear all
clc
aa = imread('p2.jpg');
ss = rgb2gray(aa);
pos = fdlibmex(ss);

strt(1,1)=pos(1)-(pos(3)/2);
strt(1,2)=pos(2)-(pos(3)/2);

face(1) = strt(1,1);
face(2) = strt(1,2);
face(3) = pos(3);
face(4) = pos(3);

Rectangle = [face(1) face(2); face(1)+ face(3) face(2); face(1) + face(3) face(2) + face(4); face(1)  face(2) + face(4); face(1) face(2)];


figure(1);
imshow (aa);
truesize;
hold on;
plot (Rectangle(:,1), Rectangle(:,2), 'g');
hold off;
```

Undefined function 'fdlibmex' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in main (line 7)
pos = fdlibmex(ss);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [FEX file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29437-viola-jones-object-detection) instead ....

Comment: Please can you explain to me how it works? i went through the example but unable to understand

Answer (score 0):

You should put this function 'fdlibmex' in your working directory besides the main script. Or you can just use addpath command to add the path of this function to your matlab workspace.

```
addpath('folder/file.m')
```

Apparently you can give a JPG image as an input, so

```
I = imread('my_image.jpg');
pos = fdlibmex(I);
```